# Replace every word after index k in list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, replace

How do you replace every word after index[3] in list?

For example, I need to change first word to "How's" and second word to "it" and third word to "going?". Then, I need to change every word to "yo" after index[3]:

```
input = "My name is bla bla bla?" 

output = "How's it going? Yo! Yo! Yo!"
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def hellohello(input):
    if type(input) != str:
        return "Input has to be string"
    else:
        new_input = input.split(' ')
        if len(input) <= 3:
            return "How's it going?"
        else:
            new_input[0] = "How's "
            new_input[1] = "it "
            new_input[2] = "going? "
            new_input[3:] = ["Yo! "]
            output = ''.join(new_input)
            return output

print hellohello("why is this not printing more yo")
```

So far I only get:

```
How's it going? Yo!
```

Comment: `new_input[3:] = ["Yo! "]` doesn't assign "every value from 3 on" to the string `"Yo! "`, it just replaces all the entries from 3 on with the single entry, instead you would need to create the duplicate entries like `new_input[3:] = ["Yo! "] * (len(new_input)-3)` or similar.

Comment: Please Read [Explain Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/509211)

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def hellohello(input):
    if type(input) != str:
        return "Input has to be string"
    else:
        new_input = input.split(' ')
        if len(input) <= 3:
            return "How's it going?"
        else:
            new_input[0] = "How's"
            new_input[1] = "it"
            new_input[2] = "going?"
            for currentIndex in xrange(3, len(new_input)):
                new_input[currentIndex] = "Yo!"
            output = ' '.join(new_input)
            return output

print hellohello("why is this not printing more yo")
print hellohello("why is this")
print hellohello("why is this yep")
```

Output:

```
How's it going? Yo! Yo! Yo! Yo!
How's it going?
How's it going? Yo!
```

By executing `new_input[3:] = ["Yo! "]`, you simply replaced the subarray of all string tokens (in the array separated by `split`) from index 3 to the last index  with a single string, "Yo!", instead of replacing each array item by itself. Basically, you referenced an entire slice of the array (`3:`) instead of just a single item.

[edit: updated solution based on correct remark that using slices and index calculus is not necessary, also added explanation of what went wrong before]

Comment: you know you can just do `xrange(3, len(new_input))` instead of slicing then adding 3 to the index each time.  Also please add description to what you changed and why you changed it or this won't help the op understand what went wrong / how to fix it themselves next time.

Comment: I updated solution based on correct remark by @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen that using slices and index calculus is not necessary. Also added explanation of what went wrong before. Not sure why down voted - this does what it is required to do by OP.

Comment: I imagine @ShubhamSharma probably downvoted because posting a whole code block with only 1-4 lines changed without comments or explanation is very rarely helpful. Now that there is an explanation it doesn't really fit that anymore.

Comment: yes, but now i remove my downvote @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

Call me lazy, but I'd probably first create a list of length `len(new_input)` full of `'Yo!'` and then swap in the `["How's", "it", "going?"]` ...

```
>>> s = "My name is bla bla bla?"
>>> new_input = s.split()
>>> output = ['Yo!'] * len(new_input)
>>> output[:3] = ["How's", "it", "going?"]
>>> output
["How's", 'it', 'going?', 'Yo!', 'Yo!', 'Yo!']
```

The problem with your code is this line:

```
new_input[3:] = ["Yo! "]
```

You're replacing multiple elements with a single element.  You could probably fix the code by doing `new_input[3:] = ["Yo! "] * (len(new_input) - 3)` which would create a list of `"Yo! "` that is the same length as the sublist that you're trying to replace.

---

<sup>You may have noticed that I used `s.split()` instead of `s.split(' ')`.  `s.split()` is the same thing as `s.split(None)` which splits on consecutive runs of whitespace (including newlines and tabs).  Basically, 
`'foo  bar\tbaz'.split()` results in `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` whereas 
`'foo  bar\tbaz'.split(' ')` would result in `['foo', '', 'bar\tbaz']`</sup>

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could explain the diff between `split()` and `split(' ')`. Though a simple issue, Many of the users don't know this.

Comment: @BhargavRao -- Sure, added a footnote since it is sort of tangent to the purpose of the rest of the post.