# Python list type list concatenation , random module

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I want to achieve : a list of posible combinations of n coin flips

What I get when I run this code : a list that contains letters from the 2 posible outcomes "heads" and "tails" . Why? I could not figure out .

```
def randomlist(n):
l = []
for i in range(n):
    a = random.randint(1,2)
    if a == 1:
        l[len(l):] = ("heads")
    else:
        l[len(l):] = ("tails")
return l


listy = randomlist(20)

print(listy)
```

Comment: Are they asking this kind of assignment somewhere?, Saw another slice assignment [a few minutes back](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37927386/4099593).

Comment: note that `("heads")` is not a tuple but a string, that slice assignment would be equivalent to `l.extend("heads")` which separates the individual characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `append` instead of slice assignment.

```
def randomlist(n):

    l = []
    for i in range(n):
        a = random.randint(1,2)
        if a == 1:
            l.append("heads")
        else:
            l.append("tails")
    return l
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate a random list of `n` coin flips, you can also use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to express the same logic in a more concise way:

```
>>> import random
>>> 
>>> def randomlist(n):
...     return ["heads" if random.randint(0, 1) else "tails"
...             for _ in range(n)]
... 
>>> randomlist(10)
['tails', 'tails', 'tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads', 'heads', 'tails', 'tails', 'heads']
>>> randomlist(6)
['heads', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads', 'heads', 'heads']
```

In the code above, random integers 0 or 1 (as opposed to 1 or 2) are generated to handily use them when deciding between `"heads"` or `"tails"` - using the fact that 0 evaluates to `False`, and 1 to `True`.

Now, if your intent is to generate *all possible* outcomes of flipping a coin `n` times, you can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). An example for `n=3` (the final output shortened for readability):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> all_outcomes = product(("heads", "tails"), repeat=3)
>>> list(all_outcomes)
[('heads', 'heads', 'heads'), ('heads', 'heads', 'tails'), ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `itertools` library. It becomes really simple like that.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> product(['heads','tails'], repeat=3) # change the repeat parameter to set the length 
<itertools.product object at 0x0000000003B715A0>
>>> import random
>>> list(_)[random.randint(0,len(_))] # get a random sequence
('heads', 'tails', 'heads')
```

This comes in handy if you need to quickly generate large number of sequences. Just save the `product` result in a variable, and retrieve a random index from it.